# Arduino and pyserial and ble

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth, pyserial, hm-10

Actually i can send data from pyhton(pyserial) to arduino through cable,but i want to do that with hm-10, normally bluetooth module which is the hc-05 ,hc-06 u can find port,
With wire or wirelles(hc-05) com7 port:

```
arduino = serial.Serial("COM7", baudrate=9600,timeout=.1)"
```

But hm-10 is ble.
what i need to write instead of com7?
or how can i solve that problem?
(windows 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pySerial library will not work with the HM-10 module because the module uses Bluetooth Low Energy (rather than Bluetooth Classic).

This means you will have to create a GATT Client to interact with a BLE GATT Server. Typically you would have the Arduino in the Peripheral role (server) and the Windows PC in the Central role (Client).

A quick internet search suggests that the GATT service on HM-10 module has the following values:

- Service UUID:  0000**FFE0**-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
- Characteristic UUID:  0000**FFE1**-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

You can check this using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)

There are a limited number of Python BLE Central libraries with [Bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak) probably being the pick of the bunch and has good examples of how to use it.